# 404 error while running jsp page in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, jsp, struts2

I'm coding a jsp page with struts framework. While running I'm getting a 404 error.

Login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
     <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="login" method="post">  
<s:textfield name="id" label="Employee Id"></s:textfield>  
<s:textfield name="name" label="Employee Name"></s:textfield>
<s:submit value="submit"></s:submit>   
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginAction.java

```
package Login;

public class LoginAction {
    private int id;  
    private String name;  

    public int getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  

    public String getName() {  
   return name;  
    }  

    public String execute(){  
        return "success"; 
}
}
```

struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0.//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="Login" extends="struts-default" namespace="/" >
   <default-action-ref name="upload" />


      <action name="login"  class="Login.LoginAction" method="execute">  
<result name="success">products.jsp</result>  
</action>  


   </package>
</struts>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Product</display-name>



   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>

    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>


   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>



     <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   </web-app>
```

products.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>product images</title>

</head>
<body>
<a href="productdetails.jsp"><img src="images/bp.jpg" class="tooltip" title="BP monitor" id="BP monitor"> </a>
<a href="productdetails.jsp"><img src="images/sethescope.jpg" class="tooltip" title="sethescope" id="sethescope"></a>


    </body>
</html>
```

The project explorer:
[image]
Result:
[image]

Comment: Your welcome page is inaccessible.

Comment: can u just make it clear?I My welcome page is Login.jsp..why is it inaccessible?

Comment: This is the error:

Comment: WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'product' in namespace: ''. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL should be http://localhost:8080/webapp/products
Your are missing webapp part, which is your war file name.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/hello/- this was my earlier project,it is working fine.so why is the new one not working?

Comment: Look closer on the project name.

Comment: Project name is Products

Comment: somebody please help me

Comment: did you do clean build and deploy updated project war into tomcat ?

Answer (score 0):

Raj,
You need to use correct case sensitive context path (war file name by default) in your URL. If your context is 'Products' try localhost:8080/Products

Also check Tomcat DOC at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Introduction